# Как сделать страницу, которая будет отображаться по умолчанию при входе на сайт без интернета?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pwa, service-worker

Если отключить интернет и зайти на YouTube через Chrome, можно увидеть такую страницу (при условии, что ранее сайт хотя бы один раз загружался в этом браузере):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал через Mozilla, Opera – нет такого.

Как это работает?

Comment: Скорее всего надо сделать кеш страницу с чеком интернет `connection_status()`. Хотя, это больше похоже на работу самого браузера как раз на сервисы гугла

Comment: @mepihindeveloper: именно. Google и Ko :)

Comment: с Service Worker не работал, а только пробовал - и кажется, через них можно  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Comment: Первая страница грузится из `(from service worker)`. Если пройтись по ним далее, обнаруживается `serviceworker-kevlar-appshell.js (from disk cache) expires: 2022 год`. И тум мы гуглим как реализован [appshell](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для этой цели вам нужно использовать **ServiceWorker**. Также вам необходимо предоставлять ваш сайт по протоколу HTTPS – Service Worker требует это по соображениям безопасности.

Ниже привожу пример кода с комментариями, который ранее я написал для одного из [проектов](https://1000.tech/ru):

```
// наименование для нашего хранилища кэша
const CACHE_NAME = 'app_serviceworker_v_1',
    // ссылки на кэшируемые файлы и страницы
    cacheUrls = [
        '/ru',
        '/en',
        '/css/style.css',
        '/js/script.js'
    ]

// период обновления кэша - минута
const MAX_AGE = 60

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    // задержим обработку события
    // если произойдёт ошибка, serviceWorker не установится
    event.waitUntil(
        // находим в глобальном хранилище Cache-объект с нашим именем
        // если такого не существует, то он будет создан
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
            // загружаем в наш cache необходимые файлы
            return cache.addAll(cacheUrls)
        })
    )
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(
        // ищем запрошенный ресурс среди закэшированных
        caches.match(event.request).then((cachedResponse) => {
            let
                lastModified,
                fetchRequest
            // если ресурс есть в кэше
            if (cachedResponse) {
                // получаем дату последнего обновления
                lastModified = new Date(cachedResponse.headers.get('last-modified'))
                // и если мы считаем ресурс устаревшим
                if (lastModified && (Date.now() - lastModified.getTime()) > MAX_AGE) {
                    fetchRequest = event.request.clone()
                    // создаём новый запрос
                    return fetch(fetchRequest).then((response) => {
                        const responseClone = response.clone()
                        // при неудаче всегда можно выдать ресурс из кэша
                        if (!response || response.status !== 200) {
                            return cachedResponse
                        } else {
                            // обновляем кэш
                            caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
                                cache.put(event.request, responseClone)
                            })
                            // возвращаем свежий ресурс
                            return response
                        }
                    }).catch(() => cachedResponse)
                }
                return cachedResponse
            }
            // запрашиваем из сети как обычно
            return fetch(event.request)
        })
    )
})
```